# Asymptotic growth of $\Delta n \choose \frac{n}{\delta log n}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

While devising a certain algorithm and analysing its running time, I've incurred into the following:

$$f( n ) = {\Delta n \choose \frac{n}{\delta log n}}$$

where $\Delta \geq 1$ and $\delta \geq 1$ are constants, and where the logarithm is in base $2$. I need to know how $f(n)$ behaves as $n \rightarrow \infty$. In the different case where we have to pick as many as $\frac{n}{\delta}$ objects out of the $\Delta n$ available objects, the asymptotic behavior would be exponential in $n$. But here where we have to pick only $\frac{n}{\delta log n}$ of them, my intuition tells me the asymptotic behavior would be sub-exponential in $n$, kind of $O( 2^{\frac{n}{log n}} )$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives, up to a small error I will ignore for simplicity and because it barely affects the asymptotics,

$$\log {a \choose b} \approx b \log \frac{a}{b} + (a-b) \log \frac{a}{a-b}.$$

Plugging in $a = \Delta n, b = \frac{n}{\delta \log n}$ gives

$$\log {\Delta n \choose \frac{n}{\delta \log n}} \approx \frac{n}{\delta \log n} \log (\Delta \delta \log n) - \left( \Delta n - \frac{n}{\delta \log n} \right) \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\Delta \delta \log n} \right).$$

We have $\log (1 - x) = -x + O(|x|^2)$ for small $x$ and using that on the rightmost term you can check that the leading term here is $\frac{n \log \log n}{\delta \log n}$. So you were close! I don't know how accurate you need an asymptotic to be but you can make it more accurate by using the full Stirling's formula, which will also be very annoying and buy you very little.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfectly accurate for my purpose. Objective was indeed to formally ascertain that the exponent is $o(n)$.